# Link structures with different types of structures in c?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I essentially want to link a struct `NodeA` to either a struct `NodeA` or `NodeB`, eg.

```
struct NodeA{
   int type;
   int data;
   void *ptr;
};

struct NodeB{
   int type;
   float data;
   void *ptr;
};

NodeA Node1;
NodeB Node2;

Node1.ptr = &Node2;
```

Then somehow read the type then tell if it's a node A or B.

```
if( Node1.ptr.type == 1){ ...
```

Is this somehow possible in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique is called "tagged values", and relies on the fact that if a struct contains another one as its first element, then duck-typing (treating a pointer to the larger structure as a pointer to the smaller, inner one) is possible, since the C standard guarantees that there can't be padding before the first element of a struct.

```
struct descriptor {
    int type;
};

struct A {
    struct descriptor base;
    int data;
};

struct B {
    struct descriptor base;
    float data;
};

enum {
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_FLOAT
};

struct A a = { .base.type = TYPE_INT, .data = 42 };
struct B b = { .base.type = TYPE_FLOAT, .data = 3.14 };

struct descriptor *desc = (struct descriptor *)&a;
if (desc->type == TYPE_INT) {
    printf("%d\n", ((struct A *)desc)->data);
} else {
    printf("%f\n", ((struct B *)desc)->data);
}
```

etc.